# Split a list of dicts containing a count value into n nodes such that the nodes have equal or close to equal sums of count

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I got a task to write a function in Python that gets a list of company campaigns and Nodes number

And it needs to evenly distribute the workload between the number of nodes

we want to send each node a similar number of campaigns (as possible).

For example

input:

```
companies = [{campaigns: {campaign1}, count: 20}, {campaigns: {campaign2}, count: 40}, {campaigns: {campaign3}, count: 15}]

nodes = 2
```

- The count key represents the number of campaigns of the same type

Expected result:

```
[{campaigns: [campaign1, campaign3], count: 35}, {campaigns: [campaign2], count: 40}]
```

how would you split the list into n nodes such that the nodes have equal (or close to) count values (which are the sums of different campaigns count key values) and keep the original order

**EDIT:**

I tried this and it gives me the right answer if I give it the example I gave as input

```
import heapq


def split_workloads(campaigns, nodes):
    result = [{'campaigns': [], 'count': 0} for _ in range(nodes)]
    totals = [(0, i) for i in range(nodes)]
    heapq.heapify(totals)
    for campaign in campaigns:
        total, index = heapq.heappop(totals)
        result[index]['campaigns'].append(campaign['campaigns'].pop())
        result[index]['count'] += campaign['count']
        heapq.heappush(totals, (total + campaign['count'], index))
    return result
```

but if I give it as input:

```
companies = [
                  {'campaigns': {'campaign1'}, 'count': 3},
                  {'campaigns': {'campaign2'}, 'count': 2},
                  {'campaigns': {'campaign3'}, 'count': 1},
                  {'campaigns': {'campaign4'}, 'count': 6}
                  ]
nodes = 2
```

I get the wrong output:

```
[{'campaigns': ['campaign1', 'campaign4'], 'count': 9}, {'campaigns': ['campaign2', 'campaign3'], 'count': 3}]
```

The correct output should be:

```
[{'campaigns': ['campaign1','campaign2', 'campaign3'], 'count': 6}, {'campaigns': ['campaign4'], 'count': 6}]
```

Comment: This problem is known as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) or the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)

Comment: Or as [multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) if the number of nodes is larger than 2.

Comment: I think the multiway number partitioning is the right direction
Thanks!

Comment: @stef Do you have any source that implements the multiway number partitioning?
I added my implementation to the post but it goes wrong for some inputs, like the one I added under 'EDIT'

Comment: See this related question [python: efficient solver for multiway number partitioning?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6113/efficient-solver-for-multiway-number-partitioning); this python package [pypi: numberpartitioning](https://pypi.org/project/numberpartitioning/); and these 7 github repositories [github: number partitioning](https://github.com/topics/number-partitioning)

Comment: @stef I checked this https://github.com/fuglede/numberpartitioning and it looked promising but doesn't always give the optimal solution

For example - 

lst = [5,5,5,4,4,3,3,1] and n = 3
The output will be:
[[4, 5], [1, 4, 5], [3, 3, 5]]
But the optimal solution would be:
[[5,5],[3,3,4],[1,4,5]]

Comment: I haven't tested this package, so I don't know. Perhaps you can raise an *issue* on the github repo. Note that the description of the repo says it implements Karmarkar--Karp algorithm, as well as several greedy algorithms. The greedy algorithms are certainly not guaranteed to give an optimal solution, so be careful which algorithm you use if you want an optimal solution.